# How to resolve (Error 40: Could not open a connection to SQL Server) in C# when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have verified that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. I have pinged the host to see if there is a connection.

I have checked the SQL Server configuration manager to see if TCP is enabled and that the default port is 1433. I checked to see if the firewall allows SQL Server and it does, but I am still getting this error:

> Error 40: Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Here is the connection class

```
class SqlDBConnection
{
    private string sql;
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand command;
    public SqlDataAdapter da;
    public SqlCommandBuilder cmBuilder;

    public SqlDBConnection()
    {
        string ConnString = "Server= 146.230.177.46//ist3; Database= ist3ea; User ID=ist3ea;Password=534525";
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
    }

    public DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        sql = "Select*  from Books";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Books");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: And have you checked that the server and other credentials work with SQL Management Studio from the same machine as you're running that code?

Comment: >>>Server= 146.230.177.46//ist3<<< means you have NAMED instance, so its port is NOT 1433

Comment: In order to make your server accept remote connections that use its name, SQL Server Browser should run. Otherwise you should write your port in the connection string instead of instance name

Comment: The problem might be on the connection string, please check these examples: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ Also, you could try to use SERVERNAME\SQLSERVERINSTANCE as Server parameter, as backslashes are required.

Comment: Sorry but I am voting for closing as a typo, the instance name is referenced using `\instancename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to connect to your **named instance** of `ist3` - the connection string ought to contain: `Server= 146.230.177.46\\ist3` (**backslashes** between IP address and instance name - **not** forward slashes!)

```
public SqlDBConnection()
{
    string ConnString = "Server=146.230.177.46\\ist3;Database=ist3ea;User ID=ist3ea;Password=534525";
    conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
}
```